# How to limit drag/resize/rotate range of svg objects?

Tags: snap.svg

Is that possible to limit a certain resize/move/rotate range for the objects inside a svg?

https://jsfiddle.net/8y56hjf7/1/

```
var s = Snap("#item");
s.drag();
```

I want the image only can be resized/moved/rotated in the red border area. No matter what I do, the image can't get out of the area. Any ideas or examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-drag-limit

Comment: Cool, very nice example. Thank you man.